# How do I nest a KeyValue pair within AWS CDK PolicyStatement AddAction method?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am currently trying to replicate another developer's powershell script functionality using the AWS CDK with a .NET application. He is generating a CloudFormation template (YAML) using VaporShell. I put the CloudFormation template below (I have made many of the names generic for this post). I put an arrow pointing to the key value pair that is giving me a headache.

```
Resources:
  rSNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: 'SNS topic'
      TopicName: 'SNS Topic'
  rSNSPolicy:
    Type: AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy
    Properties:
      Topics:
        - !Ref 'rSNSTopic'
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Condition:
              StringEquals:
                AWS:SourceOwner: 'CurrentAcct' <=== This is the key/value pair.
            Action:
              - SNS:Publish
              - SNS:RemovePermission
              - SNS:SetTopicAttributes
              - SNS:DeleteTopic
              - SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic
              - SNS:GetTopicAttributes
              - SNS:Receive
              - SNS:AddPermission
              - SNS:Subscribe
            Resource: !Ref 'rSNSTopic'
            Effect: Allow
            Sid: Default
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
      Version: '2012-10-17'
```

I have been able to generate another CloudFormation template using a C# app & the AWS CDK. It works almost perfectly EXCEPT for generating that key value pair I highlighted above. I have tried using an array, generating a new policy statement object and using the Key/Value pair object within .NET. I will put examples of each of those three attempts below and the corresponding output. Does anyone know of a way to generate the key/value pair in the same manner shown above? Using the CDK with C# of course.

**Attempt 1: Using an array of strings.**

C# Code (below):

```
var topic = new Topic(this, "rSNSTopic", new TopicProps
        {               
            DisplayName = "SNS topic",
            TopicName = "SNS topic"
        });

        var topicPolicyStatement1 = new PolicyStatement(0)
            .Describe("Default")
            .AddAwsPrincipal("*")
            .AddActions("- SNS:Publish\n" +
                        "- SNS:RemovePermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:SetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:DeleteTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:GetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:Receive\n" +
                        "- SNS:AddPermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:Subscribe\n")
            .AddCondition("StringEquals",
               new [] {"AWS:SourceOwner", "pTestAccnt"}) <=== Using an array as the second .AddCondition parameter.
            .AddCondition("aws:SourceArn", topic.TopicArn)
            .AddResource(topic.TopicArn);

        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement1);
        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement2);
```

Generated key/value pair part of the CloudFormation Template (below):

```
Condition:
   StringEquals:
      - AWS:SourceOwner
      - TestAccnt
```

**Attempt 2: Using a new policy statement object.**

C# Code (below):

```
var topic = new Topic(this, "rSNSTopic", new TopicProps
        {               
            DisplayName = "SNS topic",
            TopicName = "SNS topic"
        });

        var topicPolicyStatement1 = new PolicyStatement(0)
            .Describe("Default")
            .AddAwsPrincipal("*")
            .AddActions("- SNS:Publish\n" +
                        "- SNS:RemovePermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:SetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:DeleteTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:GetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:Receive\n" +
                        "- SNS:AddPermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:Subscribe\n")
            .AddCondition("StringEquals",
               new PolicyStatement(0).AddCondition("AWS:SourceOwner", "pTestAccnt")) <=== Using a policy statement as the second .AddCondition parameter.
            .AddCondition("aws:SourceArn", topic.TopicArn)
            .AddResource(topic.TopicArn);

        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement1);
        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement2);
```

Generated key/value pair part of the CloudFormation Template (below):

```
Condition:
   StringEquals:
      Condition: <=== This solution creates a second condition key which throws an error in AWS CloudFormation.
         AWS:SourceOwner: TestAccnt <=== This key value pair looks correct.
```

**Attempt 3: Using a Key/Value object from .NETnew policy statement object.**

C# Code (below):

```
var topic = new Topic(this, "rSNSTopic", new TopicProps
        {               
            DisplayName = "SNS topic",
            TopicName = "SNS topic"
        });

        var topicPolicyStatement1 = new PolicyStatement(0)
            .Describe("Default")
            .AddAwsPrincipal("*")
            .AddActions("- SNS:Publish\n" +
                        "- SNS:RemovePermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:SetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:DeleteTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic\n" +
                        "- SNS:GetTopicAttributes\n" +
                        "- SNS:Receive\n" +
                        "- SNS:AddPermission\n" +
                        "- SNS:Subscribe\n")
            .AddCondition("StringEquals",
               new KeyValuePair<string, string>("AWS:SourceOwner", "pTestAccnt")) <=== Using a policy statement as the second .AddCondition parameter.
            .AddCondition("aws:SourceArn", topic.TopicArn)
            .AddResource(topic.TopicArn);

        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement1);
        topic.AddToResourcePolicy(topicPolicyStatement2);
```

This approach throws an error. I suspect that it has to do with the JSII runtime compiling/interpreting the key/value pair object I used in the C# application.

The entire output from the command line (below):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Could not infer JSII type for .NET type 'KeyValuePair`2'
Parameter name: type
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Converters.FrameworkToJsiiConverter.InferType(IReferenceMap referenceMap, Type type)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Converters.ValueConverter.ConvertAny(IReferenceMap referenceMap, Object value)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Converters.ValueConverter.TryConvertPrimitive(IReferenceMap referenceMap, Object value, Boolean isOptional, PrimitiveType primitiveType, Object& result)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Converters.ValueConverter.TryConvert(TypeReference typeReference, IReferenceMap referenceMap, Object value, Object& result)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<ConvertArguments>b__0(Parameter parameter, Object frameworkArgument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ZipIterator[TFirst,TSecond,TResult](IEnumerable`1 first, IEnumerable`1 second, Func`3 resultSelector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase.<InvokeMethodCore>g__GetResult|18_0[T](<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1& )
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase.InvokeMethodCore[T](JsiiMethodAttribute methodAttribute, Object[] arguments, Func`3 beginFunc, Func`3 invokeFunc)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase.InvokeInstanceMethod[T](Object[] arguments, String methodName)
   at HelloCdk.TestStack..ctor(App parent, String name, IStackProps props) in C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\git\SomeGITRepo\SingleStackGenerator\src\HelloCdk\TestStack.cs:line 57
   at HelloCdk.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\SomeUser\Documents\git\SomeGITRepo\SingleStackGenerator\src\HelloCdk\Program.cs:line 18
(node:39548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPIPE: broken pipe, write
    at Object.writeSync (fs.js:569:3)
    at t.SyncStdio.writeBuffer (C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\gnh3dhha.5kf\jsii-runtime.js:1:165352)
    at t.SyncStdio.writeLine (C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\gnh3dhha.5kf\jsii-runtime.js:1:164892)
    at t.InputOutput.write (C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\gnh3dhha.5kf\jsii-runtime.js:1:164341)
    at t.KernelHost.writeError (C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\gnh3dhha.5kf\jsii-runtime.js:1:79440)
    at i.then.catch.e (C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\gnh3dhha.5kf\jsii-runtime.js:1:79101)
(node:39548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:39548) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Subprocess exited with error 3762504530
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution. The "dictionary" object in C# is perfect and the JSII runtime compiles it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue and the solution was not quite obvious... Posting final code snippet:

```
var topic = new Topic(this, "rSNSTopic", new TopicProps
{
    DisplayName = "SNS topic",
    TopicName = "SNS topic"
});

topic.AddToResourcePolicy(new PolicyStatement(
    new PolicyStatementProps
    {
        Principals = new IPrincipal[] { new AnyPrincipal() },
        Actions = new []
        {
            "SNS:Publish",
            "SNS:RemovePermission",
            "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
            "SNS:DeleteTopic",
            "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
            "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
            "SNS:Receive",
            "SNS:AddPermission",
            "SNS:Subscribe"
        },
        Resources = new[] { topic.TopicArn },
        Conditions = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"StringEquals", 
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "aws:SourceOwner", "pTestAccnt" } }},
            {"StringEquals", 
                new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "aws:SourceArn", topic.TopicArn } }
        }
    }
);
```